# Android Webview touch event not trigged in iframe

Tags: javascript, android, html, iframe, webview

This is an android project and I need to load a website in a webview.
And one more request here is the website needs to be loaded in a iframe.

This is done by the following step:

1. create a webview
2. I have a sample html file
3. I load my sample html file
4. I call `wewbview.loadHTMLString(sampleHtmlString, "")` to load the site from string;

Sample html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
            console.log("document touchstart");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And webview show all good on device also i can see touch event triggered.

---

Then I will add the iframe part:

1. User input a url to load for example: "https://www.facebook.com"
2. Still I load my sample html file
3. Then I replace the PLACE HOLDER in sample file to the one user input for example: `"https://www.facebook.com"`
4. Then call `wewbview.loadHTMLString(sampleHtmlString, "")`;

Updated sample html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        .webview-container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="webview-container" id="webview-container">
    </div>
    <script>
        function loadWebView(url) {
            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.src = url;
            document.getElementById('webview-container').innerHTML = '';
            document.getElementById('webview-container').appendChild(iframe);
            iframe.onload = function() {
                console.log("iframe onload");
            };
        }

        document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
            console.log("document touchstart");
        });
        loadWebView('https://www.example.com');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can see the site loaded in iframe correctly but this time touchstart not trigggered when touched.

I searched few posts then tried:

```js
function loadWebView(url) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.src = url;
    document.getElementById('webview-container').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('webview-container').appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.onload = function() {
        console.log("iframe onload");
        iframe.contentWindow.document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
            console.log("iframe touchstart");
        });
    };
}
```

But still not working and I am getting the error in console:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read a named property 'document' from 'Window': 
Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin 
"https://www.grandbrowser.com".  

The frame requesting access has a protocol of "about", 
the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". 
Protocols must match.", source: about:blank (41)
```

I also tried to remove the `"https:"` from the url according to this post:

[The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525511/the-frame-requesting-access-has-a-protocol-of-https-the-frame-being-accessed)

But then the error in console is gone but the site will not load anymore.

---

Any advice on this issue will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

---

If is ok that if there will issues to use event listener inside a iframe in different domain.

The main feature I want to achieve here is to detect:
To detect touchstart / touchmove / touchend event and then add some css animation above the loaded website in iframe.

Comment: For security reasons browser don't allow you to access certain things in Iframe if it's domain is different than parent page domain which is rendering Iframe. For debugging purpose I will suggest you to load one of grandbrowser.com page in Iframe. Once you find the issue, replace it with user input.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow